# R shiny library icons not working

Tags: r, shiny

My shiny app was working well with icpns eg calendar icon displaying till I decided to update the font-awesome folder.I read online that you can download and replace rhe folder to get the latest fonts.I did this and now no icon is working or showing after including them in my dashboard code.How can I get them to work again?

Comment: Have you tried reverting back the original font-awesome folder?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mark.
Actually I had overwritten the original fontt-awesome folder.But I got a work around.I searched for a font-awesome folder in the HTML directory of Rstudio and copy pasted this into the www folder of the shiny directory.My icons now work.